# fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) return all values of a MySQL query into array

Tags: php, mysql

This query to MySQL:

```
SELECT `group_id`
            FROM `j30_user_usergroup_map`
            WHERE `user_id` =3065
```

Is returning the following results:

[image]

However, in PHP the following code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', '');
    $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT `group_id`
        FROM `j30_user_usergroup_map`
        WHERE `user_id` =3065');
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
    print_r($result);
```

Is returning:

```
( [group_id] => 2 )
```

I want all the elements of the array, not just the 1st, as described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Loop or http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: FYI, there's really no point in using `PDO` if you're not binding your values. Take advantage of the added security it offers. And you're looking for `fetchAll()`: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches **the next row** from a result set

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks, I just don't seem to understand the meaning of next row. I do understand what first row means, but next row to me is subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two way to solve this, change `fetch()` by `fetchAll()` or use an `while` and return a new array.

1) FetchAll approch

Change:

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

By:

```
 $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

2) While approch

```
$items = array();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $items[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: fetchAll works, but in the link to the manual I provided, fetch is used.

Comment: The link from the manual states "PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches **the next row** from a result set"

Comment: @NunoNogueira se quiser pode perguntar na versão em português do site http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ :)